# Openfire where MySQL save the data of the conected rooms of an user?

Tags: mysql, xmpp, openfire

I'm looking into the MySQL database of openfire but I can't found any table where Openfire save the conected users into a MUC room. Do you have any idea of where I can found this information in the MySQL database?

Comment: When you are creating a MUC room, are you asking for a persistent room? (muc#roomconfig_persistentroom). If you're not sure, what client are you using? If you are not requesting a persistent room, all MUC information will be held in memory and never get written to the database

Comment: I'm asking for a persistent room. I am looking into the MySQL database but I can't find that information. Thanks.